# not able to run Galaxy in my cygwin terminal

Tags: virtual-machine, bioinformatics, ansible-galaxy

I'm trying to install galaxy in my virtual machine. But im not able to run the run.sh file in my terminal. im getting a error as not found and someother errors[image]

i tried to check for the python version. i think it is good.

Comment: Sorry but this cannot be answered. It's unknown what these scripts are, all one sees is an error without details. Generally, do yourself a favor and use WSL2 instread of VM/Cygwin.